# Iterating a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary where the values are list elements:

```
dict1={'A':[9,0,8],'B':[6,5,4],'C':[]}
```

Now I have to process this dictionary to check if all the values in the dictionary are empty lists; and if so, collect the keys.

Is there a better option than simply iterating through the entries?

Comment: How could you know without checking all of them?

Comment: (The question can be read multiple ways .. consider clarifying it with an example or existing code that works or doesn't work.)

Comment: I was looking for a better option than a for loop on a dictionary.We would definitely need to look through all the entries surely

Comment: only in the worst case, as Lattyware pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have a dictionary, you can't avoid having to iterate over the items in order to filter it:

```
keys = [key for key, value in dict1.items() if not value]

if len(keys) != len(dict1):
    # Do something about the mis-match
```

Comment: Very licit point @Haidro!

Answer (score 4):

```
if not any(dict1.values()):
    res = dict1.keys()
```

Comment: The advantage being that `any()` will short-circuit.

Comment: Guess it depends if having empty lists is a usual case or unusual case. If it not uncommon, you will be going over the dict1.values() twice for no reason. If unusual, this is a useful test.

Comment: @drewk Why twice? (not that I really care about that here: I believe it to be the readable way).

Comment: I suppose it is a bit ambiguously stated in the OP, but assume that the actual key that has the zero length list is relevant, the dict will need to be iterated over again to locate it.

Comment: @drewk I did not answer *that* question... the question I read states: "collect all the keys, if all the values are `[]`." :)

Comment: Pls don't get me wrong at all: This is a great shortcut. I am just pointing out the shortcut is only as solid as whether the actual keys containing the falsy lists are need. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can test the truthiness of the dict values:

```
di={'A':[9,0,8],'B':[6,5,4],'C':[], 'D':[0], 'E': []}

truthy= [k for k in di if di[k]]
falsy= [k for k in di if not di[k]]

print 'truthy:{}, falsy:{}'.format(truthy,falsy)
```

Prints:

```
truthy:['A', 'B', 'D'], falsy:['C', 'E']
```

You can also use filter:

```
truthy=filter(lambda k: di[k], di)
falsy=filter(lambda k: not di[k], di)
```